# Insert First Image into post (full-width)

Tags: shortcode

I am looking for a simple PHP function to insert the first image from the gallery into the post, full width (I am using custom post types btw). So the syntax will be:

```
<img src="xxxxx" />
```

any ideas?

many thanks
Andy

Comment: Do you mean the first image uploaded to a post or the actual `gallery` shortcode.

Comment: the first image uploaded to a post... I dont think i can use the gallery shortcode to insert an image without knowing the attachment ID..

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I use, maybe there is a better way.

```
$attachments = get_children(
                            array(
                                  'numberposts' => -1,
                                  'order'=> 'ASC',
                                  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                                  'post_type' => 'attachment'
                                  ));

               $first_attachment = reset($attachments);
               //$last_attachment  = end($attachments); or last image
               echo wp_get_attachment_image($first_attachment->ID, 'full');
```

Additional `wp_get_attachment_image` parameters found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image